# Simplify MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL query that I used to use to return mutual friends between two users, but now that I am recoding my website, I am trying to simplify this code, or at least make it better.

So here's my code below to check mutual friends:

```
SELECT a.friendID
FROM
(SELECT CASE WHEN userID = $id
    THEN userID2 
    ELSE userID 
    END AS friendID 
FROM friends 
WHERE (userID = $id OR userID2 = $id) 
    AND state='1'
) a

 JOIN
(SELECT CASE WHEN userID = $session
    THEN userID2 
    ELSE userID 
    END AS friendID 
FROM friends 
WHERE (userID = $session OR userID2 = $session) 
    AND state='1'
) b

ON b.friendID = a.friendID
```

My table is set up like this:

```
   userID -- userID2 -- state
      1 ------- 2 ------- 1
      2 ------- 3 ------- 1
      1 ------- 3 ------- 0
```

(sorry, I don't know how to do the pretty database structure design, so if someone could edit that for me...)

but for the above, when user 1 is on user 3's profile, since user 1 and user 2 are friends, and user 2 and user 3 are friends, but user 1 and user 3 are not, it should return user 2 as a mutual friend. (state 1 means friendship accepted, state 0 means friendship pending, so only if state is 1 should it be counted as a friend)

Also note that userID and userID2 can be in any order, it depends on who requests who as a friend, so like the above query does, I need to also have the "friendID" returned, as the above query does right.

Comment: well, the the above database example, $fromID would be 3, and $session would be 1

Comment: oops, my bad! $fromID shouldn't have been in there, it should have only been $id and $session. $id would be 3, and $session would be 1. I have changed my code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t.f FROM friends JOIN (

  SELECT IF(userID = $id, userID2, userID) f
  FROM   friends
  WHERE  state AND $id IN (userID, userID2)

) t ON t.f IN (userID, userID2)
WHERE  state AND $session IN (userID, userID2)
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce67a/1/0).

Comment: Thanks, it seems like your code is onto something, however I am having issues. I checked your sqlfiddle, and it does seem to work as it should there, however when I replace my current code, it returns a number of rows, around 90 or so. In addition, I need to return the other persons id, as friendID as my above code has done. And also, I don't know what exactly this query is doing, but it doesn't appear that you have it to only check rows that have a state=1.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily the fastest but simple to read:

```
Create View ActiveFriends As
Select
  UserId, UserID2
From
  friends
Where
  State = '1'
Union All
Select
  UserId2, UserID
From
  friends
Where
  State = '1'


Select
  f1.userID2 as MutualFriendId
From
  ActiveFriends f1
    Inner Join
  ActiveFriends f2
     On f1.UserID2 = f2.UserID
Where
  f1.UserID = $session And
  f2.UserID2 = $id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5748f/1/0

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to be working. :\ It looks like it should.. and I went through and changed capitalization and such, but nothing.

Comment: @DylanCross I've added a link to SQL fiddle to show it working. Maybe its a mysql version thing? Obviously you'd create the view once and just have the second part in your code.

Comment: Well actually maybe that's the problem, I've never heard of Create View, so how exactly would I use that in my statement? I just assumed you wrapped the entire thing in a mysql_query() in php.

Comment: @DylanCross How did you create your tables in the first place? Did you connect directly to mysql and type "create table ..." or is it all through PHP?

Comment: I created them in phpmyadmin. But i don't understand exactly the above code is all suppose to do, because in the 2nd select statement it doesn't have the where state=1 but the first one does.

Comment: @DylanCross Does http://skyontech.com/blog/create-MySQL-view-in-phpMyAdmin help creating the view? To see how it works you can imagine "ActiveFriends" in the second query being replaced by (Select ...) from the first query. So the state = '1' carries through.

Comment: Well, this seems to be something that just creates a new table of information or whatever, and wouldn't really work? My website is a social network, so the information changes all of the time and such. if that's relevant to this.

Comment: @DylanCross It's not a table, it's just a convenient way of giving a query a name. Any time you reference it, it's just like running the query.

Answer (score 0):

You could do :

```
SELECT userID2
FROM friends_table
WHERE userID IN ( $id, $session )
AND state = 1
GROUP BY userID2
HAVING COUNT(userID2) >= 2
```

friends_table :

```
user_id | friend_id | state
-----------------------------
   1    |     7     |    1
   2    |     3     |    0
   7    |     1     |    1
```

User 1 and 7 are friends, user 2 wants to be friends with user 3, but user 3 hasn't responded yet.

Comment: I'm not  entirely sure what your code is trying to do, my code above in my question works exactly as it should, I'm just trying to get a simplified/better one

Comment: You are having to check whether it's userID or userID2 you're interested in, and the doing it again for the other person. In my answer for users to be friends they exist in both columns. If your working with/in a "follow" situation you won't need the "state" column.

Comment: @Stack101 I don't think Dylan would have (1,7) and (7,1) as separate rows in his database, though you could easily use this technique with the ActiveFriends view from my query. Actually, that seems to produce a smaller query plan than my answer... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5748f/3

Comment: It just seems easier for every type of friend query. Get all friends : `SELECT * FROM friends_table WHERE userID = $session AND state = 1`. Get friends of friends : `SELECT * FROM friends_table AS f JOIN friends_table AS fof ON f.userID2 = fof.userID WHERE f.userID = $session AND f.state = 1 AND fof.userID2 != $session AND fof.state = 1`. The following/subscribe model (without confirmation from the other person [no state]) also seems to work better too (ie : google+, twitter, pinterest...)

Answer (score -1):

at the first glance I would say that using intersect is a good solution
so this query should do the trick for you

```
SELECT userID2
FROM friends 
WHERE userID = $fromID 
INTERSECT
SELECT userID2
FROM friends 
WHERE userID = $theOtherID
```

EDIT:
another less clear solution would be

```
SELECT userID2
FROM friends INNER JOIN friends f2
USING (userID2)
WHERE friends.UserID = $fromID AND f2.userID = $theOtherID
```